# GCP Cloud Console throws a 500 error while loading the custom domains tab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

After setting up a wildcard mapping on one of my app's custom domains (following the instructions in the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#wildcard_mappings), the "custom domains" tab under app engine >> settings in the cloud console won't load with a message "failed to load".
Looking in the Developer Tools in Chrome, under the Network tab, there is a json object describing a 500 server response with a tracking ID and a message: ""Not a valid domain name: '*.my-domain.com'" (where my-domain is my app's custom domain name). The app itself is still serving requests on that custom domain, and the wildcard setting seems to be working, but I can't access any of the custom domains settings due to this error.
Has anyone encountered this situation ? Help much appreciated.
Thanks

---UPDATE---

12 hours later, the problem seems to be fixed. Nothing changed by me, the custom domains tab now loads normally.

Comment: Just to be clear, were these `500` errors essentially limited to the Developers Console via this AJAX request?  If so, there is no [known outage](https://status.cloud.google.com/) with the Developers Console.  Happy to hear this issue is no longer present and can only surmise it was transient.  Should this recur, I would strongly suggest filing defect report on the [Cloud SDK public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list) and attaching a [HAR file](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/) containing the `500` responses.

Comment: Yes those errors were limited to the dev console, and specifically to the custom domains tab. I can only guess that they were related to the wildcard entry I made on one of my custom domains. Anyway, all is normal now. If it reoccurs I will follow your recommendations. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As this issue did not recur, it seems fairly reasonable to assume this was a transient issue.  It also seems fair to assume this was most likely a backend issue about which not much could have been done from the client side.

When encountering these types of issues with the Developers Console, I'd recommended the following:

1. **Log out of the console, close the tab, come back to site and log back in**.  It is possible sometimes that the front end handling the session fails to respect session affinity when load balancing or fails to get a proper token.  Then the erroneous state remains while logged in.  Thus, logging out and back in again can start a fresh session.
2. If the issue is reproducible beyond a fresh session and indeed occurs every time a given page or service is requested, **consult the [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/)**.  Though uncommon, there may be an outage with the **Google Cloud Console**.  Updates on such an outage may be reported there.
3. If no widespread issue exists, this may be an isolated issue requiring further investigation.  Consider **searching the [Google Cloud Platform public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/list) for open issues** with similar symptoms.  If the issue lies with the backend, you may not be the first to encounter the error and someone else may have already reported it.
4. Failing to find any exiting public issue, **open an new issue** attaching the label `Product-DeveloperConsole`.  To save time with the investigation, consider attaching a [HAR capture](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/) to the report as the request/response information can be very helpful.  This can be done from the [Network panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading#record_network_activity) in the Chrome Developer Tools.